# Using MIL-DTL-38999 circular connector for Ethernet applications

Tags: ethernet, standard

A MIL-DTL-38999 connector based on insert arrangement has a different service rating (M, N, I and II). Service rating of M shows a suggested operating voltage of 500VDC (pin to pin and pin to shell).

Does that mean that this connector cannot be used for Ethernet (10, 100, 1000 Base-T) as isolation of 2250VDC for 60s is required to meet the IEEE802.3 Standard between frame ground (shell) and MDI pins (A+/-, B+/-, C+/-, D+/-)?

Most decent density 38999 pin insert arrangements are service rating M and a lot of products in the market use M rated insert for Ethernet. I wonder how they meet this requirement.

Comment: Isolation voltage is generally greater than operating voltage. Much greater. So, no this doesn't mean any such thing. (There may be reasons you can't use that connector, but this isn't it).

Comment: You are correct about it. The test voltage listed for service rating M is 1300VAC which is not far off from 1500VAC/2250VDC requirement. But this number is still lower 1500VAC.

Answer (score 4):

In many MIL applications, we are not looking for 100% compliance with an industry standard such as IEEE802.3.  Compliance is needed to ensure that a piece of equipment works with whatever it's going to be connected to - not some arbitrary piece of commercial gear.  Things we usually care about are physical and link layers of the OSI model, and maybe the network (IP) and transport (UDP/TCP) layers.

With '38999 connectors, you can achieve the desired DC voltage isolation requirement of IEEE802.3, if that's really needed, by 1) not using pins next to the connector shell and 2) removing pins around the Ethernet signals.