# Ethernet in MIL-DTL-38999 connector

Tags: connector, ethernet, rj45

I am hoping to use a MIL-DTL-38999 circular connector for 10/100 Mb ethernet in acc. to IEEE802.3.
So the insulation voltage should be at least 1500VAC for 1 min.
Most connectors I have seen during my search on Mouser and Digikey are service rating M and hence only 1300VAC.
I have searched the exchange and found a similar question ([Link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/484151/using-mil-dtl-38999-circular-connector-for-ethernet-applications)), where the answers state that for IEEE802.3 compliance the insulation rating of the connector must be higher than 1500VAC for compliance.
However, searching “RJ45 dielectric withstanding voltage” on Google yields a plethora of RJ45 connectors with a 1000VAC rating. As RJ45 is THE Ethernet connector how can this be? I am not aware of RJ45 being used for anything other than Ethernet these days. Am I missing something here?

Comment: "I am not aware of RJ45 being used for anything other than Ethernet". RJ45 is the mainstay of structured cabling systems that are widely used to carry phone lines, serial data lines, analog or digital audio signals, video signals, KVM remote connections and pretty much any form of signal running up to Gigabit speeds.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me Finbarr. I guess that these RJ45 connectors, with a 1kV isolation voltage spec, aren’t suitable for Ethernet (IEEE 802.3), but can be used for any of the other connection types you mention?

Comment: They're the standard connector for Ethernet everywhere since the disappearance of thin and thick coax Ethernet decades ago. Where did you see the 1500VAC requirement?

Comment: I have seen the 1500VAC many places online. For instance here: https://incompliancemag.com/article/designing-ethernet-cable-ports-to-withstand-lightning-surges/. This page states: “The IEEE standard 802.3 for Ethernet specifies a 1500 VRMS isolation barrier between the cable and the Ethernet PHY chip...”.

Comment: For specific wording see [here](http://www.ieee802.org/3/interp/interp-6-1102.pdf).

Comment: "between the cable and the Ethernet PHY chip" - yes, that's done by the transformer. Doesn't mean you can't have a connector with a lower isolation voltage on the cable, you just need to make sure it has enough clearance to make up the 1500V.